# Magento layout XML custom helper

Tags: magento

I'm trying to pull in a system configuration value to a layout file. I figured the only way to do this was to create a function in my Data.php helper and then use the function in the layout xml. For some reason, it doesn't work.

```
public function getStoreVar() {
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('path/to/var');
}
```

Then in the xml I have something like

```
<block type="my/module" template="path/to/template.phtml">
    <config_id helper="module/getStoreVar" />
</block>
```

I have a Mage::log on the getStoreVar function and can see that it isn't even being called. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out what I was doing wrong. Realized the code I was referencing to do this, addLink, had the helper inside an action tag with the helper on an argument for the action method. Using a method from my block class fixed it for me. For example:

```
  <action method="setStorVar">
    <var helper="module/getStoreVar" />
  </action>
```